# Trim a video and add the boomerang effect on it with FFmpeg

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing, android-ffmpeg

I have a given source video which is 30 seconds long in total.
Now I want to trimm the first 5 seconds and apply the boomerang effect on it. That's the command where I am currently:

```
ffmpeg -i src.mp4 -y -an -filter_complex "[0]trim=start=0:end=5[a];[a]reverse[r];[a][r]concat,loop=0:250,setpts=N/30/TB" out.mp4
```

Im relatively new to ffmpeg and I'm trying to understand the principals, but I struggle with it a bit. After reading some docs, I understanded that the first brackets [0] are the source stream for the manipulation and the leading ending brackets are the output stream name, so I can continue to process it with other manipulations like concat etc.

That's what I tried with [a], which should act as the output stream of my trimed video. But this didn't worked well.

Another approach what I found is to use `-ss 0 -t 5`,but this would trim it at the end of the processing, what would be inefficient since ffmpeg would apply my manipulation on the complete 30 seconds and throw away the 25secs afterwards.

What did I understand wrong and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

> Another approach what I found is to use `-ss 0 -t 5`,but this would trim it at the end of the processing, what would be inefficient since ffmpeg would apply my manipulation on the complete 30 seconds and throw away the 25secs afterwards.

Remember that all flags apply to the *next* in-/output file.

If you want to read only the first 5 seconds of the input file, you have to put the `-ss 0 -t 5` *before* the `-i` flag:

```
ffmpeg -ss 0 -t 5 -an -i src.mp4 -y -filter_complex "[0]split[b][c];[c]reverse[r];[b][r]concat" out.mp4
```

This will run the filter chain only on the first 5 seconds of `src.mp4`.

If you put the `-ss 0 -t 5` after the input file, it will apply to the output `out.mp4` instead, so the complete input file would be processed but only the first 5 seconds of the result written to `out.mp4`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
ffmpeg -i src.mp4 -filter_complex "
[0]trim=start=0:end=5[a];
[0]trim=start=0:end=5,reverse[b];
[a][b]concat
" -an out.mp4 -y -hide_banner
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Yes this indeed works, but wouldn't this take unessecary processing time, since it trims the video two times ? Isn't there a way to trim it once and reuse it ?

Comment: you can split trimmed video: `[0]trim...[a];[a]split[a][b];[b]reverse[b];[a][b]concat`